# String Interpolation not getting updated after change to object in Viewmodel in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have an element in my View in Aurelia that is not getting updated when an object from its Viewmodel is getting updated. I've seen the documentation about Pub/Sub and Event Aggregators, however this seems a little heavy-handed for what I want to do, since I am not trying to communicate between two different resources, but rather just within a View and its Viewmodel.

When a change occurs to the object in the Viewmodel, I don't know how to correctly update (or trigger an update to) the string interpolation in the View.

My code is as follows

**myview.html**

```
<h1>My List</h1>
<ul>
    <li repeat.for="group of modelObject.groups">
        <span>${group.id}</span>
        <span repeat.for="state of group.region">${state}</span>
    </li>
<ul>
<button click.delegate(editModelObject())>Edit</button>
```

**myviewmodel.js**

```
constructor()
{
    this.modelObject = {
        <other stuff>,
        "groups": [
            {
               "id": "default",
               "regions" : ["NY", "CT", "NJ"]
            },
            {
               "id": "west",
               "regions" : ["CA", "OR"]
            }
        ],
        <more stuff>
    }
}

editModelObject() {
    <something that updates both the id and regions of a group in this.modelObject>
}
```

For some reason, the states are correctly changing in the view, but the id's are not. Do I need to use something like Pub/Sub to get the two-way binding to work correctly? Or is there a simple thing that I am missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works if you change a property of one of the array's objects. But this doesn't work if you assign one of the array's index because this would require dirty-checking. See https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/64

To solve your problem you should use `splice()` instead of indexed assignment. For instance:

```
const newItem = { id: 77, name: 'Test 77', obj: { name: 'Sub Name 77' } };
//instead of this.model.items[0] = newItem; use below
this.model.items.splice(0, 1, newItem);
```

Running example https://gist.run/?id=087bc928de6532784eaf834eb918cffa